# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem: font awesome support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, font-awesome

According to [the changelog](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/#changelog) `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem supports [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) since v.2.0.9. So how to turn on this support in project? Font awesome icons are not available for me by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Using Font Awesome wiki page](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome) in their GitHub project.  It is more recent than the v2.0.9 release, so I assume it is the current recommended practice.

Comment: In order to use it you need to add the `gem 'less-rails'` to your _Gemfile_. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It is now supported in `twitter-bootstrap-rails` by default.

Just add icons into your html code, like this:

```
<i class="icon-refresh"></i>
```

More icons and examples here: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 2):

The *twitter-bootstrap-rails* gem has more dependencies since twitter bootstrap css uses LESS. In order to turn font-awesome on in your project you need to add

`gem 'less-rails'`

`gem 'therubyracer'`

in the `:assets` group of your *Gemfile*.
After that you are able to use it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can add icons to your HTML code, like this:

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

However, if you want place icons in Rails link_to helper use the ilink_to helper method. Follow the steps below:

1) Add the gem to your assets group in the Gemfile:
    gem 'less-rails-fontawesome'

2) Run *bundle install*:

3) Be sure that *@import 'fontawesome';* is uncommented in app/assets/stylesheetes/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less.

4) Use *ilink_to* helper instead of *link_to* helper.

```
<%= ilink_to "upload-alt", "Edit", edit_post_path(post), class: 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

Obs: Precede the link text with the icon name stripped off icon- prefix

These instructions are here: https://github.com/wbzyl/less-rails-fontawesome